# How to render elements if space is available for that element using ngFor in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ngfor

I am creating an Angular 2 component to show tags (like shown in StackOverflow under questions). But in my scenario, I only have a limited space to show tags because I can only use one row. If there are more tags that cannot be shown, I want to indicate them using a number showing how many tags are left unseen.

for example,

if there is enough space - **[apple][mango]**

if not - **[apple][mango][banana][+3]**

Is there a way I can use a custom pipe (with ngFor) to do this?

At the moment I am rendering all the tags using ngFor and positioned them in a row using css flex.

```
<div 
    *ngFor="let tag of tags" 
    class="tag" 
    [ngClass]="'tag--' + tag.type">
    {{tag.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is certainly doable if you care about the length as number of characters. If you're interested in the actual rendered widths of individual characters, it will be much more complex.

Comment: unfortunately I need to calculate with actual element widths. At the moment I'm trying to calculate widths in component init (ngOnInit) using element.offsetWidth. But child element widths are not available at that point.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up is, manually checking top position of element's bounding box in `AfrerViewInit` lifecycle hook and removing elements until top values of both first and last elements match.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.hidden = 0;
  let children: Element[] = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0].children;
  let topOfFirst = children[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let topOfLast;
  for (let i = children.length - 2; i > 0; i--) {
    topOfLast = children[children.length - 1].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (topOfLast > topOfFirst) {
      children[i].remove();
      this.hidden++;
    }
  }

  // remove counter if hidden count is 0
  if (this.hidden === 0) {
    topOfLast = children[children.length - 1].remove();
  }
}
```

[image]